# mysql select query return nothing

Tags: mysql

I was querying mysql database using

```
select * from `item` where `word`= '碰瓷' limit 1
```

there is Chinese character in the query string, nothing is returned. I use heidi to query the same text, I can get the expected result. mysql version is 5.6.15. what confuses me is I copy the same code the, restore the same data on another mysql database, all worked fine

Comment: might worth mentioning I use petapoco to access database

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a N before your string.

```
select*
from item
where word=N'碰瓷'
limit 1
```

You need the N because you are looking for double byte characters

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I tried this select * from `item` where `word`= N'违和' limit 1, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmm try to change the datatype of word from varchart to nvarchar. After that you still need to use the big N.

Comment: there is no nvarchar datatype in mysql, only varchar